# Ember Select box: unwanted observer firing on page load

Tags: ember.js

This has been an ongoing conceptual problem for me.

I set an observer on a select box that I wish to fire only when a **user** selects a different option.
The problem is, that the observer fires on page load, presumably because data is being loading into the select box.

How would I accomplish something where only the user switching the box fires an observer. Perhaps an action? How would that be done with a select box?

**Template:**

```
{{view Ember.Select content=seasons
      optionLabelPath="content.number"
      optionValuePath="content.id"
      selection=selectedSeason
 }}
```

**Controller:**

```
seasons: [{id: 313, number: 1}, {id: 4325, number: 2}, {id: 56543, number: 3}],

selectedSeason: function(){
  //last season
  return this.get('seasons')[2]
}.property(),

selectedSeasonChanged: function(){
  alert('This fires on page load! Bad!')
  var seasonId = this.get('selectedSeason.id');
  this.transitionTo('season', seasonId)

}.observes('selectedSeason')
```

Comment: Can you clean up your copy/paste errors (I assume those are from copy pasta...). Aside from the syntax errors your code looks fine. `observes` shouldn't run on page load unless some other code that isn't shown here is causing it.